# "You earned a new privilege!" is misaligned

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Compare Chemistry's new design:

> [image: Misaligned "You earned a new privilege!"]

With another site (say Software Recommendations):

> [image: Normal "You earned a new privilege!"]

It would be nice if it was easier to tell *what* privilege I earned, along with it being in alignment.

Comment: You kids ......

Comment: @jonsca We don't come looking for bugs; bugs come looking for us. ;)